# How to check migration from Neo to CF went successfully?

Tags: migration, sap-cloud-foundry

I'm unable to know if the application had successfully migrated to the Cloud Foundry environment.
How do I check if the application is pointing towards CF environement?
For Android, I read it in a blog that we are supposed to change the server url in the code's configuration folder but I didn't find anything for iOS.

I had created a sample Neo mobile application through the iOS SDK and then migrated it to the Cloud Foundry environment. How do I know if the application was succcessfully migrated and wheather or not it's pointing towards the Cloud Foundry environment?

The application is running in Xcode.